# Selenium script to launch load a url to check if we can get a login page in the existing chrome app (with history of it) on remote linux server

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

**Requirement:** I have to logged in to a particular website for certain task. Once we login manually, it was kicking me out due to session expiry after certain time. So then, I have to write a script to load the website and if I see the login page I have to enter credentials and log into it and if I don't see the login page, then it means it is already logged in and I do nothing.

For this, I've been trying to write a selenium script to launch chrome app with required url and see if I can get the login page. But, I'm facing a problem.

**Problem:** Every time I run the selenium script, it launches a new chrome window which doesn't have any history details of the existing chrome app of the server. Hence every time I load the website, it is loading the login page, it seems selenium is launching a new incognito type of window which doesn't have history of the existing chrome app of server.

I'm running it on a linux server. This is not helping me. I've searched a lot in google and in stackoverflow, everywhere I see how to attach to the same session of chrome once the selenium scripts starts, but I couldn't find how to start with already existing app of the chrome in the server.

Can someone help in this?
I'm attaching the code, what I have tried ..

```
import sys
import time

import typer
import requests

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from typing import Tuple


chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--verbose")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=selenium") 
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


def login_dr_paul_account():
    driver.get('https://*****.*****.com/#/')
    driver.find_element("id", "username").send_keys("username")
    driver.find_element("id", "password").send_keys("password")
    driver.find_element("id", "submitButton_label").click()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # typer.run(main)
    typer.run(login_dr_paul_account())`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Loading the default browser in selenium can be achieved as below:**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument(
    "user-data-dir=<give path of default browser profile>") 

# user-data-dir location for win: C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default
# user-data-dir location for linux: /home/(user)/.config/google-chrome/Profile/ 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/driver/chromedriver",
                          chrome_options=options)

# Open the URL
driver.get('https:url.com/')
```

Follow the above and tweak it accordingly in your code. See if it works.

Comment: No @shawn it is still loading a new window even though I tried with the above user-data-dir as my profile in which I have logged into the url already.