# How to keep the cookies active?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So I'm using selenium to do some automations.
I'm using `browser.add_cookie` to add my account cookies into Facebook for easily login, but the issue is once I'm logged in with the cookies, If I used for example: `browser.get("https://www.facebook.com/pages/creation");` or any other url in Facebook, the cookies log out and Facebook asks me to re-login.
So my question is how to keep my account cookies working in every section in Facebook and I don't have to re-add it everytime I use `browser.get()` ?

I've tried to use `browser.add_cookie()` everytime I got to a new url in Facebook but it doesn't seem to be a practical solution.

Comment: you need to navigate to Facebook in order to set the cookies.  At that point a new session may have begun.  This would conflict with any cookies you write and FB would force a re-login.  Why not just automate the login?

Comment: logging with cookies is much easier and much faster, and sometimes Facebook gives me wrong credentials when I log in with my email and pass even tho i typed them right, that is why i prefer cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium by default opens browser in incognito mode. If you want to use the existing browser settings(like logins, cache, cookies etc.), you can force selenium to open your default browser profile/or a custom profile of your choice.

Check this if it helps how to load default profile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75590359/7598774
https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-use-a-specific-chrome-profile-in-python-selenium

Comment: This is not really my issue, my issue is when I log in Facebook using the cookies, the browser automatically reloads and logs me out of Facebook account.